# How many positive and even factors does $2013!$ have?

Tags: problem-solving

How many positive and even factors does $2013!$ have?

So I know that $2013 = 2\times1006 + 1$

So, does that mean $2013!$ has $1006$ even factors?

Comment: It's not that simple ...

Comment: Where did you get this?

Comment: It's not even true.

Comment: You might want to start by looking at a much smaller factorial, and seeing what the answer is in that case.

Comment: Lots! With a little table of the primes less than $2013$, one can find the answer by hand in an hour, say two hours with checking.

Comment: Your last few questions revolve around the number 2013, looks like someone is posting competition questions

Comment: Note that for an even positive integer $n=2m$, the number of even divisors of $n$ is the number of divisors of $m$, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We list the ingredients and leave it to you to do the cooking. Let $p_0^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ be the prime power factorization of $2013!$, where $p_0=2$.

Then the number of (positive) factors of $2013!$ is $(a_0+1)(a_1+1)\cdots (a_k+1)$.

The number of odd factors is $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots (a_k+1)$.

Subtract to find the answer  $a_0(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_k+1)$ to our problem.

To find the $a_i$, note that by a standard result
$$a_i=\left\lfloor\frac{2013}{p_i}\right\rfloor+ \left\lfloor\frac{2013}{p_i^2}\right\rfloor+ \left\lfloor\frac{2013}{p_i^3}\right\rfloor+ \cdots.\tag{1}$$
The computations are unpleasant, though not as bad as it might seem. A list of the primes is useful for the calculation.

For example, all the $a_i$ for $p_i\ge 1007$ are equal to $1$. Now all we need is a *count* of the primes between $1007$ and $2013$ to find their contribution to the answer. They contribute a multiplicative factor $2^s$, where $s$ is the number of primes in the interval.

For primes between $672$ and $1006$, the $a_i$ are equal to $2$. Things continue in a quite simple way (only one term in Formula (1)) until we get to primes $\lt\sqrt{2013}$.

Comment: "...note that by a standard result." Now the post is self-contained. See my answer! =)

Answer (score 3):

Define, for any positive integer $m$, the function$$\Lambda(m)=\begin{cases}\log p&\text{ if }m=p^k\\0&\text{ else }\end{cases}$$

Note then that if $m=p_1^{\ell_1}\cdots p_r^{\ell_r}$ we will have  $$\log m=\sum_{k=1}^r\ell_k\log p_k=\sum_{d\mid m}\Lambda(d)$$

where the sum runs through all the divisors of $m$.

*Reason:* The $\log p_k$ entry accounts for $\Lambda(p)$ when $p$ is prime, whilst $\Lambda(p)$ will appear $\ell$ times for each divisor $p,p^2,\ldots,p^{\ell}$. On the other hand, any divisor of the form $d\cdot d'\;,\;d\neq d'$, will vanish in the right hand sum, so it will not appear on the left.

Now, suppose $m=n!$ for some $n$. We thus can write $$\log m!=\sum_{k=1}^m\log k=\sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{d\mid k}\Lambda(d)$$

Note that $$\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)=\sum_{d\geqslant 1}f(d)\left[d\mid n\right]$$

where $[P]=1$ if $P$ is true, and $0$ else. For example $$\begin{align}
  f(1) + f\left( 2 \right) + f\left( 4 \right) + f\left( 8 \right) &= f(1) \color{green}{\left[ {1\mid 8} \right]} + f(2)\color{green}{\left[ {2\mid 8} \right]} \cr 
   &+\; f(3)\color{red}{\left[ {3\mid 8} \right]} + f(4)\color{green}{\left[ {4\mid 8} \right]} \cr 
   &+\; f(5)\color{red}{\left[ {5\mid 8} \right]} + f(6)\color{red}{\left[ {6\mid 8} \right]} \cr 
   &+\; f(7) \color{red}{\left[ {7\mid 8} \right]} + f(8)\color{green}{\left[ {8\mid 8} \right]}\\&+\;f(9)\color{blue}{\left[ {9\mid 8} \right]}+\cdots \end{align} $$

But the red terms are $0$, the green terms are $1$, and all other blue terms vanish since $[d\mid n]=0$ whenever $d>n$, so both sides coincide.

Then we can write $$\displaylines{
  \sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {\sum\limits_{d\mid k} {\Lambda (d)} }  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {\sum\limits_{d \geqslant 1} {\Lambda (d)\left[ {d\mid k} \right]} }  \cr 
   = \sum\limits_{d \geqslant 1} {\left( {\Lambda (d)\sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {\left[ {d\mid k} \right]} } \right)}  \cr} $$

where the sum extends over all numbers $d$ greater than $1$, and which by the above argument, is a actually a finite sum.

But, what is $$f(d)={\sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {\left[ {d\mid k} \right]} }\text{ ? }$$
This counts the number **multiples** of $d$ that do not exceed $m$. This numbers is $\left\lfloor \dfrac md\right\rfloor,$ the greatest integer preceding $\dfrac md$.  Can you prove this?

Thus, we get that $$\log m! = \sum\limits_{d \geqslant 1} {\Lambda (d)\left\lfloor {\frac{m}{d}} \right\rfloor } $$

Now, the sum on the left will consist only of prime power of $p^k$ since $\Lambda$ vanishes on the others, so we can write $$\log m! = \sum\limits_\stackrel{\Large p\text{ is prime}}{{k \geqslant 1}}  {\Lambda \left( {{p^k}} \right)\left\lfloor {\frac{m}{{{p^k}}}} \right\rfloor } $$ but $\Lambda\left(p^k\right)=\log p$; so $$\log m! = \sum\limits_\stackrel{\Large p\text{ is prime}}{{k \geqslant 1}}  {\log p\left\lfloor {\frac{m}{{{p^k}}}} \right\rfloor } $$

This means that $$m! = \prod\limits_\stackrel{\Large p\text{ is prime}}{{k \geqslant 1}} {{p^{\left\lfloor {m/{p^k}} \right\rfloor }}} $$

This gives $m!$s prime factorization, as you can see. You can refer to Andre's answer to see how to use this to calculate what you want.

**ADD** To give some insight on Rob's answer. Suppose we wrote $m$ in base $p$ for a fixed prime $p$, say $$m = {\alpha _0} + {\alpha _1}p + {\alpha _2}{p^2} +  \cdots  + {\alpha _t}{p^t}$$ Then for each $k$; $$\frac{m}{{{p^k}}} = {\alpha _0}{p^{ - k}} + {\alpha _1}{p^{1 - k}} + {\alpha _2}{p^{2 - k}} +  \cdots  + {\alpha _k}{p^0} +  \cdots  + {\alpha _t}{p^t}$$ so that $$\left\lfloor {\frac{m}{{{p^k}}}} \right\rfloor  = {\alpha _k}{p^0} +  \cdots  + {\alpha _t}{p^{t - k}}$$

Now summing through $k=1$ to $t$ gives $$\displaylines{
  \sum\limits_{k = 1}^t {\left\lfloor {\frac{m}{{{p^k}}}} \right\rfloor }  = {\alpha _1} + {\alpha _2}\left( {1 + p} \right) + {\alpha _3}\left( {1 + p + {p^2}} \right) +  \cdots  + {\alpha _t}\left( {1 + p +  \cdots  + {p^t}} \right) \cr 
   = {\alpha _1} + {\alpha _2}\frac{{{p^2} - 1}}{{p - 1}} + {\alpha _3}\left( {\frac{{{p^3} - 1}}{{p - 1}}} \right) +  \cdots  + {\alpha _t}\left( {\frac{{{p^t} - 1}}{{p - 1}}} \right) \cr 
   = {\alpha _0} - {\alpha _0} + {\alpha _1}\frac{{p - 1}}{{p - 1}} + {\alpha _2}\frac{{{p^2} - 1}}{{p - 1}} + {\alpha _3}\left( {\frac{{{p^3} - 1}}{{p - 1}}} \right) +  \cdots  + {\alpha _t}\left( {\frac{{{p^t} - 1}}{{p - 1}}} \right) \cr 
   = \frac{{{\alpha _0} + {\alpha _1}p + {\alpha _2}{p^2} + {\alpha _3}{p^3} +  \cdots  + {\alpha _t}{p^t}}}{{p - 1}} - \left( {\frac{{{\alpha _0} + {\alpha _1} +  \cdots  + {\alpha _t}}}{{p - 1}}} \right) \cr 
   = \frac{{n - {\sigma _p}\left( n \right)}}{{p - 1}} \cr} $$

as Rob has said.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/307873), for a prime $p$, the number of factors of $p$ in $n!$ is
$$
\frac{n-\sigma_p(n)}{p-1}
$$
where $\sigma_p(n)$ is the sum of the base $p$ digits for $n$. Thus, we can factor $2013!$ as

$$
2013!=2^{2004} 3^{1002} 5^{501} 7^{333} 11^{200} 13^{165} 17^{124} 19^{110} 23^{90} 29^{71} 31^{66} 37^{55} 41^{50}\cdots
$$
The number of factors of $2013!$ would be
$$
(2004+1)(1002+1)(501+1)(333+1)(200+1)(165+1)(124+1)(110+1)(90+1)\cdots
$$
The number of odd factors of $2013!$ would be
$$
(1002+1)(501+1)(333+1)(200+1)(165+1)(124+1)(110+1)(90+1)\cdots
$$
Thus, the number of even factors would be
$$
2004(1002+1)(501+1)(333+1)(200+1)(165+1)(124+1)(110+1)(90+1)\cdots
$$
far more than $1006$.

Comment: How do you obtain $\sigma_p(n)$? I mean, surely the computation isn't something short.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Sum the base-$p$ digits; divide by $p$ and sum the remainders (repeat as needed).

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **No, 2013 has not 1006 factors**. There are much more.

Think simple: How many even factors has $5!$? An even factor is one that is divisible by 2.

$5! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 = 120$

The factors you're interested in are 2,4,6,8,12 (5 factors). So your system obviously doesn't work

To check a given number, you can use a simple program (Python):

```
def findEvenFactors(n):
    fac = 1
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        fac *= i
    counter = 0
    for i in range(2,fac,2):
        if fac % i == 0:
            counter += 1
    return counter

print(findEvenFactors(10))
```

12! has 719 even factors!

Comment: $2013!$ has $2012$ even factors less than $4026$ (all the even numbers less than $2013$ and their doubles). There are many more that are larger.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't really understand "even factors" until I read your comment.